# Using multi-queue NICs in Linux

Tags: multithreading, networking, network-programming, multiprocessing, packet-capture

I've read a lot about Receive Side Scaling (RSS), Receive Packet Steering (RPS) and similar technologies, but I'm at a loss about how I can actually use those in my programs, that is to partition incoming packets between different threads/processes.

I do know about PF_RING, but I suppose there must be some base support in the Linux kernel itself. After all, Interl for example boasts about its RSS technology in its website and claims Linux support. Also, RPS is outside the scope of PF_RING. Another reason I'm reluctant about using PF_RING is that they have patched network drivers, and some of those patched drivers seem to be out of date.

I've extensively googled the topic, but the best I've found is about enabling RSS or RPS support, and not how I can programatically use them.

Comment: On what basis are you partitioning the packets? And what protocol (TCP? UDP?) are the packets you're trying to partition?

Comment: TCP is my main target (although UDP is also being planned). As to partitioning, as far as I know, RSS and RPS partition packets based on a 5-tuple: protocol, source address, destination address, source port and destination port.

Comment: Then unless you're writing a kernel driver or modifying the kernel, there's nothing for you to do. Figuring out which connection a received TCP packet goes with is purely a kernel function.

Comment: I suppose since RSS is supported by the kernel, and RPS is actually a Linux kernel facility, then the code must already be there in the kernel and/or drivers, and there must be *some* way to use it!

Comment: Your question still makes no sense. The kernel figures out which connections TCP packets belong to. There's nothing special you need to do to use these features other than use a kernel that supports them. There is no leeway in how the kernel partitions TCP packets. There's only one way to do it, and that's the way the kernel does it. So there's nothing programmatically for you to do.

Comment: I don't see a reason why not (not that I am reluctant to dirty my hands with kernel space programming, if I must!). Perhaps you are not completely clear about what RPS actually is?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11182/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-homayoon)

Comment: Normally this kind of technic is used in Network processors , where network accelerators generate a unique tag for flow and each flow could be mapped to different cores. That means the schedular is in H/W to do that. Sameway you might have to write your own schedular to schedule the packet between application threads. I assume that RPS mentioned above should be H/W schedular and it could schedule on cores for application you might need your own SW schedular.

Comment: No, as a matter of fact, RPS is a software technique developed for older single queue NICs.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel 3.19 introduced SO_INCOMING_CPU socket option. With that the process can figure out to which CPU the packet was originally delivered.

> Alternative to RPS/RFS is to use hardware support for multi queue.
>
> Then split a set of million of sockets into worker threads, each one
>   using epoll() to manage events on its own socket pool.
>
> Ideally, we want one thread per RX/TX queue/cpu, but we have no way to
>   know after accept() or connect() on which queue/cpu a socket is
>   managed.
>
> We normally use one cpu per RX queue (IRQ smp_affinity being properly
>   set), so remembering on socket structure which cpu delivered last
>   packet is enough to solve the problem.
>
> After accept(), connect(), or even file descriptor passing around
>   processes, applications can use :
>
> int cpu;  socklen_t len = sizeof(cpu);
>
> getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_INCOMING_CPU, &cpu, &len);
>
> And use this information to put the socket into the right silo for
>   optimal performance, as all networking stack should run on the
>   appropriate cpu, without need to send IPI (RPS/RFS).

[https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/408257/][1]